# Optimization notice after installing Yosemite

Tags: macos

After I installed Yosemite I got a notice saying that performance may suffer until my Mac is optimized. What exactly does it mean and do I have to do anything?

Answer (score 8):

It's updating the Spotlight index.
There's nothing to do, just let it happen.

Comment: It may also be related to `Photo Library Migration Utility` which I see is an active process consuming some CPU during this time (Note I did not intentionally initiate any photo migration of any kind after installing Yosemite on top of Mavericks. Whatever this is, it appears to be an automated response to upgrading. I also see `mds` and `mdworker` processes which jibes with Tetsujin's answer.)

Comment: BTW - Photos didn't exist when this answer was written.

Comment: Yes, the install I referenced above was a 10.10.3 install. 10.10.3 is the first version of Yosemite with the new `Photos` app, and the `Photo Library Migration Utility` appears to be related to this new app. So my comment about PLMU applies only to 10.10.3 and later.

Answer (score -2):

Try using below links, both worked well for me

- http://www.cultofmac.com/299974/os-x-yosemite-tips/
- http://www.hightechdad.com/2014/10/23/13-tips-optimize-mac-yosemite-installation/

Comment: While these are useful tips, they don't really fit into the scope of the question.